# Can not find Javacardx Package

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, javacard

I want to write an applet that send/receive Extended APDU. As far as I know, I must use `javacardx` package. but I can't find it to download. 
I searched everywhere for it,but all I found is documents!

Can anybody give me a download link?

**Note: I use Eclipse**

I appreciate your time and consideration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would find a `javacardx` package in [Root ▶ src ▶ openjcvm ▶ vm_lib ▶ javacardx](https://code.ohloh.net/project?pid=f4e_xzOpDAA&prevcid=1&did=src%2Fopenjcvm%2Fvm_lib%2Fjavacardx&cid=FAR_lLuJyIs&fp=174585&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&filterChecked=true&projSelected=true) of the [openjcvm/ (Another Open JavaCard Virtual Machine)](https://code.google.com/p/openjcvm/).

A [2.2.2 Java Card Development Kit is available here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-2.2.2-oth-JPR). It is an old one (2006).

```
java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows.zip\
  java_card_kit-2_2_2\
    java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do.zip\
       api_export_files\javacardx\apdu
       api_export_files\javacardx\framework
```

Comment: Thank you MR.VocC - I want all `javacardx.APDU` ,  `javacardx.framwork` , `javacardx.security` and  `javacardx.crypto`. but the link only have `javacardx.crypto`

Comment: @User1-St as shown here (https://github.com/abysshal/OpenJCVM-H/blob/abb14b1bbd0e536f260416acc9d5e86fc5dcf1ef/src/applet/com/sun/javacard/samples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java), those other packages aren't in `javacardx`, only in `javacard`. As in http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/APDU.html, using java card specs (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/documentation/index.html)

Comment: Dear Vonc, Please take a look here : [link](http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/app-notes-2.2.2/extapdu.html) do you mean this is wrong?

In the **Sending and Receiving Extended APDU Commands** section :
To write an applet that takes advantage of extended length, follow these steps:

1. Implement the `javacardx.apdu.ExtendedLength` interface in your applet.

So I thing `APDU` is in `javacardx` , no?

Comment: And Also in the middle of the page I can see `javacardx.framework.ExtendedLength`

Comment: @User1-St 2.2.2? That is an *old* version of Java Card, pre 3.x, back from 2006. I have edited my answer to add a link to dowload the dev kit.

Comment: Dear VonC, I copied contents of  `api_export_files\javacardx\apdu` and `api_export_files\javacardx\framework` in the **Plugin** folder of Eclipse, but yet I can't import them in my applet! why? it each avacardx folders there only one **.exp** file. Do I need **.jar** files?

Comment: @User1-St I agree, I didn't find `.class` either in those folders. I suspect you need to import the jar files, which might contain those classes (I didn't explorer those)

Comment: @User1-St is there any jar in that javacard SDK zip file, that you could add to your build libraries path in your Eclipse project. I see those jars in `java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows.zip\java_card_kit-2_2_2\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do.zip\lib`

Comment: Dear VonC, I added all of them to _plugin_ folder already, but nothing changed. those are for simulating and creating `.cap`(=converted applet) files and so on.

Comment: @User1-St I wouldn't add then to the plugin folder, but rather in your Build Path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2727683/6309

Comment: I don't understand what you said. I want to when I type `import javacardx.` in top of my program, Eclipse suggest me APDU, Framework, and Security. but it suggest me only crypto. I right clicked on the project name and build path and so on ... (like the link) but nothing change

Comment: @User I mean modify the properties of your project in order to reference those jars in the build parh of your project. See the link I mention.

Comment: thank you dear VonC, I modified the properties referenced those jars in the build parh of my project. but nothing changed.

Comment: @User1 it would be interesting to test a more recent version of that Java Card SDK, and see if the situation improves then.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real Javacard that support SDK 3.x yet.all the cards support 2.x

Comment: @User1 ok. Did you find any other jar in the zip contained in the SDK? I am on my phone right now, so I cannot look in details.

Comment: There are JC 3.01 implementations out there, even on 5 Juli.

Comment: @owlstead I agree, but it was my understanding the OP was stuck with an old version of JC.

Comment: And I agree with that, it's a response to the comment of User1-St that claims that there are no 3.x cards yet. Just using the SDK should solve the issues, I don't see why it doesn't. Just link to the lib/api.jar for compilation and the exp files for the converter and everything should be fine...