# Can anyone tell me why the second "here" link doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

On [this](http://dummycode.com/p/logger/) page there are two "here" links on the same line and the second doesn't work.

My css can be found [here](http://dummycode.com/f/style.css). I am unsure why it is any different than the "header" div because the links in the header div work even though they are on the same line.

The specific code in question is posted below.

**CSS**

```
#body {
        line-height:1.5em;
    width:700px;  
    margin:auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    padding:12.5px;
    color:#4e443c;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:"Courier";
        text-align:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="body">
            <h3>Logger</h3>
                Logger is a java library that allows you to log to a log file easily. <a href="Logger.jar">Download</a> <span> the .jar file and then add it to your build path. 
                For Eclipse instructions see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/2727723">here</a>. 
                For command-line instructions see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/2096298">here</a>. 
                Then add the code <i>Logger log = new Logger();</i> to your class to initialize the logger and then you can use either <i>log.log(String);</i> or <i>log.logAndPrint(String);</i> to print to the log. 
                The <i>logAndPrint</i> method prints to the console as well as the log file while the <i>log</i> method only prints to the file. 
                Below is an example driver program. <br>
                <script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/https://github.com/dummycode/Logger/blob/master/Example.java?footer=0">
</script>
                        <a href="/p">Back</a>
        </div>
```

I've tried different things such as `display:inline-block` or using `span` tags, but most of these mess up the format of my page.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please check my answer bellow your question.

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/ctdrhkhk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `social` id div is over that link.
You need to change the positioning on that twitter bird.

Add the following style to the social id div:

```
#social {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your CSS code

```
#social {
position:fixed;
width:70px;
height:130px;
left:80%;
padding-left:100px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

reduce your padding of `padding-left:100px;` and make it `left:80%;`, it will be fine for you

Comment: Damn, I thought I had gone over everything. Little did I know it was an issue arising from an entirely different area.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use position fixed for this. Try this.

```css
    #body {
      line-height: 1.5em;
      width: 700px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding: 12.5px;
      color: #4e443c;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Courier";
      text-align: left;
      float: left;
    }
    #social {
      width: 70px;
      height: 130px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      float: left;
    }
```